# Validar número telefónico y celular

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Estoy validando un campo que puede ser un numérico telefónico o número de celular, pero al momento de colocar el valor me acepta del 7 al 9, yo quiero que se valide solo si tiene 7 o 9 caracteres. ¿Cómo puedo arreglarlo?

```
\d{7,9}
```

**Código**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var telefono = $("#campo_telefono")

var expreg = /\d{7,9}/;

if (expreg.test(telefono))
    alert("El telefono es correcta");
else
    alert("El telefono NO es correcta"); 
});
```

Comment: deberias agregar el formato del numero que estas ingresando

Comment: y no es mas facil contar la cantidad de caracteres del string?

Comment: y otra cosa, por favor da ejemplos de formatos validos e invalidos. y aclara para que lenguaje es la regex

Comment: Es cierto, tendré más cuidado, y tienes razón, mejor es contar el número de caracteres.

Comment: si no agregas el lenguaje y las cadenas validas e invalidas, borra la pregunta. Asi como esta, no tiene mucho sentido.

Comment: Ahora lo agrego, voy a colocar el código completo :) .

Comment: @gbianchi Existe diferencia de expresiones regulares para cada lenguaje?. No es solo uno para cualquier lenguaje que soporte Regex?

Comment: Validar teléfonos con Regex es una ciencia por si mismo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634139/phone-validation-regex/18626090

Comment: @EverZevallos, la verad es que sí hay diferencias. No todos los lenguajes soportan las mismas implementaciones de regex. Pero *normalmente* suelen diferenciarse en las cosas más *avanzadas* por decirlo así. Prácticamente cualquier implementación soportará lo que has utilizado en tu solución, así que en este caso no hay problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta expresion valida: solo digitos de 0 a 9 y entre llaves ({N, M}) rango de cantidad de digitos; ejemplo: de 7 a 9 digitos.

```
^[0-9]{7,9}$
```

Si necesitas solo una cantidad de digitos; ejemplo: solo 7 digitos.

```
^[0-9]{7}$
```

Si necesitas cantidad de digitos exactos; ejemplo: solo 7 o 9 digitos.

```
^(\\d{7}|\\d{9})$
```

Comment: Hola @EverZevallos, estuve probando tu validación y acepta 8 caracteres. Solo debe aceptar 7 y 9 caracteres.

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal la respuesta fue modificada.

Comment: WOW, gracias amigo @EverZevallos, esto si reducirá unas lineas de código que tengo :)